# Ignore "Could not find layer" on GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wms

If WMS is called for multiple layers and one requested layer does not exists there will be no response.
For example if I request layers called A and B and B does not exists I get:

```
<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.1.1" ><ServiceException code="LayerNotDefined" locator="layers">
Could not find layer R16:B
</ServiceException></ServiceExceptionReport>
```

Instead I would like to get the layer A which actually exists.

URL used for request:

http://gs-wms:8081/geoserver/R16/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES=&FORMAT=image/png&SRS=EPSG:900913&WIDTH=256&HEIGHT=256&LAYERS=R16:A,R16:B&ZOOM=13&BBOX=1130045.0261680458,7792907.90773029,1134936.995978297,7797799.877540542

How can that be done?

Comment: why would you request a layer that doesn't exist?

Comment: I have an inventory that is updated automatic once per day and containing instance A and B.
But layers in Geoserver is only being updated once per week.
So users can "accidentally" request something that does not exists.
So instead of returning nothing I would like the Geoserver to return what it has.

Comment: The server works now as it must according to the WMS standard `A server shall throw a service exception (code="LayerNotDefined") if an invalid layer is requested`. I would recommend to update also the Geoserver once per day. An option could be to implement some sort of pre-prosessing/re-writing between user requests and Geoserver. Or to split GetMap into sereral GetMaps, one per layer.